# Как добавить дополнительный параметр блоку, с помощью css или html?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть стиль:

```
.text {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 1234px;
  margin-top: 98px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Для одного div это работает, но для другого мне необходимо добавить **gap: 66px**.
Создавать новый стиль не очень красиво, в интернете не могу правильно задать вопрос, поэтому задаю его здесь.

Comment: Сделайте еще один класс, которому установите `gap: 66px` и этот класс добавьте нужному элементу с классом `.text`

Comment: Это бессмысленно, поскольку такой отступ я больше использовать не буду. Мне нужно его использовать 1 раз

Comment: У меня ощущение, что вы надеетесь на какую-то неведомую магию, которая решит проблему без единой строчки кода )) Если нет никаких отличительных параметров нужного элемента, которые можно использовать в качестве селектора, а добавление класса считаете бессмысленным, то прописывайте ему этот стиль инлайн.

Comment: Очень вам рекомендую ознакомиться с BEM, он решит ваши подобные проблемы. Но начинайте его учить только если уверены в своих знаниях HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете добавить еще один класс самому блоку. Это примерно будет выглядеть так :

**html**

```
<div class='text'>Первый блок без gap</div>
<div class='text text_gap'>Второй блок с gap</div>
```

**css**

```
.text {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 1234px;
  margin-top: 98px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.text_gap{
  gap: 66px
}
```

Также в крайнем прям случае(очень не рекомендую так делать, мешает для читаемости кода) можете прописать в самом блоке. Сам **css** это практически не затронет. Выглядеть это будет так:

**html**

```
<div class='text'>Первый блок без gap</div>
<div class='text text' style='gap:66px'>Второй блок с gap</div>
```